# WEB API + IIS Express + debugging = missing requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm have a very strange issue.
I've got a web API project which is working great. I've built a little .Net app to connect to the API and this works.

When I attached the debugger, I can always log in and sometimes I can get or post data, however there will be a call to the same method which may have just succeeded which times out. Sometimes it's the first call after the login.

My first thought was what's wrong with my code? I looked and looked but couldn't see anything. I checked the stack trace, nothing there helped. I put a break point on the ASP begin request and it's not hit.
I Powered up fiddler and the request is never even acknowledged by ASP .net. Where does it go?

Could this be some weird issue with IIS Express or my machine or even my network? Or even some configuration issue i've screwed up?

Any one got any ideas where i should start looking or any tools which may help?

Comment: I would check this "little .Net app", maybe it is not sending requests for some reason?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. It's sending them. If I stop debugging the web API project and deploy to a local IIS server it seams to work.

Comment: I'm replicating my issue with unit tests now and i'm getting the following: The thread ... has exited with code 259 (0x103)
Looks like a know bug with VS 2013. Anyone got any tips to help?

Comment: I think it may be linked to this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812144/vs2013-reports-incorrect-thread-exit-code